# Select Distinct On while Order By a different column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I'm coming from a MySQL background, where GROUP BY worked very differently than in Postgres. In Postgres - and apparently any standards-based SQL database - you have to group by all selected columns, while in MySQL you can handpick which ones to group by.

I read that you can get an equivalent effect with `DISTINCT ON`, and for the most part that's the case. The hitch is that you have to `ORDER BY` all the distinct columns, and this ordering has to be the left-most ordering. That's a problem when I want to order primarily by another column.

Right now my query looks like this:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT ON (eventable_id, eventable_type)
           events.eventable_id, events.eventable_type, events.*
  FROM events
  WHERE <query>
  ORDER BY eventable_id, eventable_type, events.created_at DESC
```

I would like to swap around the order by to look like this:

```
  ORDER BY events.created_at, eventable_id, eventable_type DESC
```

Any advice for getting this to work?

Comment: What's the primary key of your table? And your Postgres version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are selecting `events.*`, you shouldn't add `eventable_id`, and `eventable_type` to the output columns redundantly. Would result in duplicate column names. You know that you don't have to include the columns in the `DISTINCT ON` clause in target list, right?

Also, it's probably faster to use `eventable_type DESC` right away, since you have that in your final sort order. That's allowed, too.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (eventable_id, eventable_type)
       *
FROM   events
WHERE  <condition>
ORDER  BY eventable_id, eventable_type DESC, created_at DESC
```

@Denis already covers the rest: make that a subquery and order as you like in the outer query.

The **alternative** would be a subselect with `GROUP BY` and `max()`, but that yields multiple columns per group, when the latest `created_at` per group is not unique. (May or may not be desirable.) And it's probably still slower than `DISTINCT ON` with an additional `ORDER BY` step. Test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

```
SELECT e.*
FROM   events e
JOIN  (
   SELECT eventable_id, eventable_type, max(created_at) AS created_at
   FROM   events
   WHERE  <condition>
   GROUP   BY 1, 2 DESC
   ) sub USING (eventable_id, eventable_type, created_at) -- maybe not unique
WHERE  <repeat condition if dupes may be eliminated>
ORDER  BY e.created_at, e.eventable_id, e.eventable_type DESC
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I was unfamiliar with subqueries. They open up a lot of doors.

Answer (score 1):

If Postgres complains, use a subselect:

```
select * from ( ... ) q order by ...
```

(If it does, though, I'd take it as a hint that the query plan will suck.)

Comment: This can be painfully slow and won't support LIMIT or OFFSET properly.

Comment: @KevinParker: Then again, any query where you group by some column and order by another is going to be slow... :)